# How to add 2 rows in Gridview footer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a grid to display no of leads. In that I have to display Page wise total as well as Grand total. Is it possible to show it in 2 different rows in Footer?
Give me some suggestions. I have to add 8 columns in grid.

Answer (score 4):

you can do this lots of ways, but one of them is to use TemplateField

here is format for your gridview (put your content in the cells)
...

```
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr><td><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltField1" Text='<%# Bind("field1") %>'></asp:Literal></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltField2" Text='<%# Bind("field2") %>'></asp:Literal></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
```

...

Comment: friend i have to add it in footer. So that i can assign individual links to Column elements and footer elements.

Comment: just switch headertemplate to footertemplate

Comment: and you can put anything in the <td></td>

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a custom GridView class by inheriting from the GridView type.

```
namespace CustomControls
{
 public class CustomGridView : GridView
    {
        private string _pageTotal;

        public string PageTotal
        {
            get { return _pageTotal; }
            set { _pageTotal = value; }
        }

        private string _grandTotal;

        public string GrandTotal
        {
            get { return _grandTotal; }
            set { _grandTotal = value; }
        }

        public CustomGridView()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnRowCreated(GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
            {
                e.Row.SetRenderMethodDelegate(CreateFooter);
            }
            base.OnRowCreated(e);
        }

        private void CreateFooter(HtmlTextWriter PageOutput, Control FooterContainer)
        {
            StringBuilder footer = new StringBuilder();
            footer.Append("<td>" + this._pageTotal  +"</td>");
            footer.Append("</tr>");
            footer.Append("<tr>");
            footer.Append("<td>" + this._grandTotal + "</td>");
            footer.Append("</tr>");
            PageOutput.Write(footer.ToString());          
        }
    }
}
```

Then use the 'Register' page directive to refer to your custom control.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc" Namespace="CustomControls" %>
```

Add your control to the page, make sure ShowFooter is set to true.

```
<cc:CustomGridView ID="GridView1" ShowFooter="true"></cc:CustomGridView>
```

You can then set the 'PageTotal' and 'GrandTotal' properties.

```
GridView1.PageTotal = "5";
GridView1.GrandTotal = "10";
```